# Magento 1.9 - use regular price instead of special price in dynamic price bundles

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, pricing

I've been working on this for some time with no luck. Basically, what I want to do is change the way bundle pricing works in Magento 1.9 so that, for each of the individual products in a bundle product, it uses the regular price at all times, even when the simple product in the bundle has a special price.

So for example, when I have a bundle that contains a simple product with a regular price of $19.95, I want the dynamic price of the bundle to be calculated using the $19.95 even when I put the simple product on special for $15.00.

I identified `getSelectionFinalTotalPrice` in `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price` as the most likely place to change the code, but it seems no matter what I do it always returns the simple product's special price.

This is the code in its unmodified state

```
public function getSelectionFinalTotalPrice($bundleProduct, $selectionProduct, $bundleQty, $selectionQty,
                                            $multiplyQty = true, $takeTierPrice = true)
{
    if (is_null($selectionQty)) {
        $selectionQty = $selectionProduct->getSelectionQty();
    }

    if ($bundleProduct->getPriceType() == self::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) {
        $price = $selectionProduct->getFinalPrice($takeTierPrice ? $selectionQty : 1);
    } else {
        if ($selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceType()) { // percent
            $product = clone $bundleProduct;
            $product->setFinalPrice($this->getPrice($product));
            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                'catalog_product_get_final_price',
                array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $bundleQty)
            );
            $price = $product->getData('final_price') * ($selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceValue() / 100);

        } else { // fixed
            $price = $selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceValue();
        }
    }

$price = $this->getLowestPrice($bundleProduct, $price, $bundleQty);

    if ($multiplyQty) {
        $price *= $selectionQty;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

It all looks fairly straightforward, especially for dynamic bundles - there's really only one price calculation. I tried commenting out the call to `getLowestPrice` but it still returned the same incorrect values.

I'm hoping someone might be able to help with some advice as to how to go about this, I've been tearing my hair out for weeks over this.

Comment: its not good practice to change in core file but you want to change then change  `final_price` to `price`

Comment: Oh I never change a core file, always override.Unfortunately, making that change had no effect, the bundles are still using the special price of the individual bundle items rather than the base price.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Did you find a solution?